# Join statment in controller not working Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

Works perfectly in routes but does not work in the controller. What might be wrong?

```
public function index()
{
    $positions = DB::table('position')
        ->join('company', 'position.company_id', '=', 'company.id')
        ->select('position.*', 'company.name')
        ->get();

    // Just to check if it's working
    print_r($positions);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin FatalErrorException in PositionController.php line 17:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found if i add it in use, i get BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2258:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()

Comment: you need to add this code at the top of your class. `use DB;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this to your controller:

```
use DB;
```

Or you can use this clause:

```
$positions = \DB::table('position')...
```

Controller just can't find `DB` class, because you didn't show it the path to `DB`.

Comment: You should always be importing the _full_ namespace.

Comment: @James, my example works. An example from official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#running-queries

Comment: I know it works, but as I said in my answer above, you need to use the full import in the event that the `app.aliases` setting is removed and `DB` won't lookup.

Comment: Hey, that's what are alieases for. I'm always using shorts where it's possible, that's why we're using frameworks and not raw php. )

Comment: Yes... Until somebody removes it. This is why most packages are naff, because of bad practice. You're assuming it's going to remain in there. At any point Taylor could remove these and you'll have to go through all of the code.

Comment: True, but your example can be broken someday too. For example, when Otwell will decide to change component namespace again, like he did before (even in minor releases).

Comment: Potentially, yeah. Using full namespaces is inherently better. It's verbose and you know exactly what's being included without having to look around trying to find out how `DB` can be imported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `DB` facade.

You'll want to import the *full* namespace for this facade in the event that it's removed from the `app.aliases` array.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```